# PHP - RegEx problem

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have strings that are being read from a PHP file, for example:

```
<?php
// Dream Portal (c) 2009-2010 Dream Portal Team
// DreamPortal.english.php; @1.1

global $scripturl, $context;

// General Strings
$txt['forum'] = 'Forum';
$txt['dream_portal'] = 'Dream Portal';
$txt['dp_core_modules'] = 'Collapse or Expand this Module';
$txt['dp_who_forum'] = 'Viewing the forum index of <a href="' . $scripturl . '?action=forum">' . $context['forum_name'] . '</a>.';
$txt['dp_who_portal'] = 'Viewing the portal index of <a href="' . $scripturl . '">' . $context['forum_name'] . '</a>.';
$txt['dp_who_page'] = 'Viewing the page &quot;<a href="' . $scripturl . '?page=%1$s">%2$s</a>&quot;.';
?>
```

And here's the REGEX that I'm using currently that does what I need:

```
$data = file_get_contents('./'.$language.'/'.$file.'.'.$language.'.php');

$codes = array (
    '/(\' \. \$)(.+?)( \. \')/',
    '/(\= \$)(.+?)( \. \')/',
      '/(\' \. \$)(.+?)(\;)/',
    '/(\[\')(.+?)(\'\])/',
    '/<\?php/s', '/\?>/s', '/<\?/s'
);
$html = array (
    '{$2}',
    '= \'{$2}',
    '{$2}\';',
    '[$2]',
    '',
);
// Since we don't have the values for the vars.
$data = preg_replace($codes, $html, $data);
```

HOWEVER, since these strings are constantly changing, it may happen that a string like this is needed/inserted into any of the $txt array variables:

```
$txt['dp_who_page'] = 'Viewing the page &quot;<a href="'.$scripturl.'?page=%1$s">%2$s</a>&quot; . ';
```

Where the variable is bunched up with the `.` and the end of the string variable has this `. ';` which is different from what it was stated above, which was this:

```
$txt['dp_who_page'] = 'Viewing the page &quot;<a href="' . $scripturl . '?page=%1$s">%2$s</a>&quot;.';
```

In either of those cases, I need it to return the above $txt['dp_who_page'] like so:

> Viewing the forum index of {context[forum_name]}.

Currently it doesn't work right with the 2nd case.

How can I do this using the following preg_replace code above for both cases listed above?  What needs to be changed?

I am using the `eval()` php function to extract the variables.

OK, here is the entire function:

```
function loadLanguageFile($language, $file) {

    $temp = array();

    $data = file_get_contents('./'.$language.'/'.$file.'.'.$language.'.php');

    $codes = array (
        '/(\' \. \$)(.+?)( \. \')/',
        '/(\= \$)(.+?)( \. \')/',
          '/(\' \. \$)(.+?)(\;)/',
        '/(\[\')(.+?)(\'\])/',
        '/<\?php/s', '/\?>/s', '/<\?/s'
    );
    $html = array (
        '{$2}',
        '= \'{$2}',
        '{$2}\';',
        '[$2]',
        '',
    );
    // Since we don't have the values for the vars.
    $data = preg_replace($codes, $html, $data);

    // We must change this because they are global.
    $data = str_replace('$txt', '$langEditor_txt', $data);
    $data = str_replace('$helptxt', '$langEditor_helptxt', $data);

    eval($data);

    if (isset($langEditor_txt)) {
        $temp['txt'] = $langEditor_txt;
        unset($GLOBALS['langEditor_txt']);
    }
    if (isset($langEditor_helptxt)) {
        $temp['helptxt'] = $langEditor_helptxt;
        unset($GLOBALS['langEditor_helptxt']);
    }

    return $temp;
}
```

You can go here to see what I am trying to accomplish, basically, I want to allow strings to be translated into languages easier, based on the English strings of these languages:  [Language TEST using this function to load the language](http://acs.graphicsmayhem.com/test3/index.php). Click on a language (currently only spanish, french, english available), than edit the language and you will see the preg_replace take affect.  Also, if you edit the DreamPortal language, it is a good example of what it is supposed to do.  Also, the Default text textarea boxes are (after you click on a language `View` link, than click on the `Create It` link) are loading up the english strings from the actual english files in all languages.  So the preg_replace is using this to input that specific string definition into the Default text textarea.

Comment: I think you need to **completely** rethink youre i18n implementation.

Comment: Can someone please help me?  I will be using this preg_replace on multiple languages.  And needs to support most, if not all languages.  If the strings need to be edited so that it is a better system for i18n, please let me know what would be best for this?  Thanks :)

Comment: It's really difficult to understand what your regexes are supposed to accomplish. Also: use double quotes if it spares some escaping. And if it's just for translating strings, use the damn gettext functions and sprintf.

Comment: OK, edited question so that it includes the entire function (I'm guessing you guys don't need help understanding what the parameters are for in that function).  And also supplied a LINK so you can see what it does and the purpose of this script and code.  Thank You for any help you can offer on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you're doing this, but the immediate problem seems to be those here-and-gone-again spaces.  The immediate *solution* would be to make the spaces optional:

```
'/(\'\s*\.\s*\$)(.+?)(\s*\.\s*\')/',
'/(=\s*\$)(.+?)(\s*\.\s*\')/',
'/(\'\s*\.\s*\$)(.+?)(;)/',
'/(\[\')(.+?)(\'\])/',
'/<\?php/s', '/\?>/s', '/<\?/s'
```

`\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters.

Comment: Is there a better way to shorten all of those regular expressions?  I'm open to more options for sure.  Thanks, bytheway, it works :)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use [`gettext()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php). This way you can use gettext catalog files, which are editable with tools like [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/index.php) (which uses [translation memory](http://www.opentag.com/tm.htm) as well).

Comment: I don't understand how to use `gettext()`, seems that the string gets passed to it, but how exactly?

Comment: You just call the function. like `_('String i need to translate')` and provided you have added that string to the translation table it returns the translated string. You do have to set up the locale and bind the translation table first. but thats all gone over in the gettext documentaion. Personally im not a fan of gettext because you have to use a binary format for the translation tables, I prefer xliff myself which is XML based and thus human readable. Zend_Translate is great in this respect because it supports a number of formats (xliff and gettext included) but uses a single interface.

Comment: it also supports position placed text replacement out of the box similar to what youre trying to do.

Comment: So, wait, using your method, all translation strings will be coming from the database instead of the files?  Wouldn't that be a security risk, and/or cause problems in some languages for some databases (especially if strict is set on the database?)?

Comment: @SoLoGHoST: No, gettext and its variations don't require a database. All text strings and translations are stored in .mo or .po files.

Comment: @SoLoGHoST: As Mario says a "translation table" is not necessarily a "database table". Its usually a file, in the case of gettext .mo or .po... my preference is xliff. However for non static strings - for example article or actual page content in a CMS that is stored in the db so there isnt an issue with doing that for your static strings - except that it actually makes them harder to manage and incurrs the overhead of having to do DB hits.

Comment: Ok, so you would need a .po/.mo file for each separate language (reg. and UTF-8)?  Also, what does an .po/.mo file look like?  Did a search on it, but don't have any clue to what it looks like.  Is it a regular text file?  How are the strings defined?

Comment: @SoLoGHoST: No they are binary files. You have to use a program to edit them like Poedit which styu mentions in his answer (Agian another reason i prefer xliff). You need on for each language yes. Everything youre ding in terms of data should be presented and sotred with UTF-8 character encoding if youre doing an i18n project.

Comment: Does Gettext have the ability to deal with TM (like Poedit TM) from command line?

Answer (score 1):

If i were you i would use the native `gettext` features as already suggested or [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html) or another i18n library.